# How to get each total of a dynamically created table in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was able to get the sum total of each rows of all table but I don't know how to get the total of each table.here is the code, the script for creating dynamic table is fine so I didn't include it just this part.

this is for getting the total of all the selected class from the the table 
including the dynamic table.
but I cant get the total of each table because they have the same elements.

```js
        function customduty(){
   var customduty = 0,

   amount = document.querySelectorAll('.customduty'), i;
      for (i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
          customduty += parseFloat(amount[i].value || 0);
   }
   $('.tot_customduty').val(customduty);
  }
```

```html
<table id="addr0" style="display: inline-block;font-size: .75em" class="table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th style="width:100px"></th>
     <th style="width:100px"></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;background-color:orange">1</td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" name="category" class="" style="width:100px">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">AHTN CODE</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="ahtn[]" class="" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['desc']; ?>" class="" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">FOB</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="fob[]" class="fob dv1sum" onkeyup="onkeyupsum()" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">FREIGHT</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="freight[]" class="freight" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">INSURANCE</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="insurance[]" class="insurance dv1sum" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">O/C</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="oc[]" class="oc dv1sum" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">D/V</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="dv1[]" class="dvs" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">D/V</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="dv2[]" class="dvp" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">DUTY</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="customduty[]" class="customduty" onkeyup="customduty()" style="width:100px">
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   
  </table>
```

Comment: Post your code. What you have tried so far

Comment: How can we help you without any code context?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i posted the code below

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Comment: @ErrolBoneo I've added the Javascript code you posted - we just need some relevant HTML now, especially since that code looks fine.

Comment: yeah I'm trying to figure out on how to post the html part here

Comment: @ErrolBoneo When you edit the question, look for the link that says "edit the above snippet" (just below the "run code snippet" button).  Click that and put the HTML in the corresponding window.  Don't forget to delete the answer you posted below ;)

Comment: @Archer thanks i just need to clean my html part its a little messy right now I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: is anyone there?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the total of the rows from the first table with this code, 
my problem is that it doesn't sum the rows in each table of dynamically 
created ones.and after getting the sum of the first rows in all the table I wanted to 
divide the total from the first rows of each table and display it under each 
first rows of all table. Any help will much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.oc').change(function(){
    var tot_fob = parseInt($('.tot_fob').val());
    var freight = parseInt($('.freight').val());
    var insurance = parseInt($('.insurance').val());
    var oc = parseFloat($('.oc').val());
    var result = parseFloat(tot_fob) + parseFloat(freight) + parseFloat(insurance) + parseFloat(oc);
    $('.dvp').val(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: If this is part of the question and not an answer then you need to edit the question and post this there, then delete this as it should not be posted as an answer.

Comment: Also, if this is an attempt to answer, you should probably add the Javascript tag to the question

Comment: ok I'll try to update my question and include the code properly